# Ruby script match host names from links in HTTP data

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote the following little ruby script to extract from bing.com the hostnames matching some IP.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

ip = '198.103.247.102'

# Get the domains
uri = URI.parse("http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A#{ip}&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=ip%3A#{ip}&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

begin
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  domaindata = http.request(request)
  domaindata.code
  domaindata.body
  domaindata["cache-control"]
  domains = domaindata.body.scan(/<a href="(.+?)" h=/)
rescue => err
  #puts "I don't want to print this #{err.message}. Hence commented"
end

if domains.nil?
  puts "[!] Domain not found"
  exit(1)
else
  puts "[+] Size: #{domains.size}"
  domains.each do |hostname|
    hostname =~ /^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/
    hostname = $1
    puts "- #{hostname}"
  end
end
```

For some reason I got this instead the expected data:

```
[+] Size: 28
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
- http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108" class="button
```

Without the domain regex I get this:

```
[+] Size: 28
- ["/?scope=web&amp;FORM=HDRSC1"]
- ["/images/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;FORM=HDRSC2"]
- ["/videos/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;FORM=HDRSC3"]
- ["/maps/default.aspx?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;mkt=sv&amp;FORM=HDRSC4"]
- ["/news/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;FORM=HDRSC6"]
- ["/explore?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;FORM=HDRSC5"]
- ["/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;go=Submit&amp;qs=n&amp;form=QBRE&amp;pq=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;sc=0-0&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2&amp;setmkt=sv-se&amp;setlang=en-us"]
- ["javascript:void(0);\" class=\"id_button\" id=\"id_l"]
- ["javascript:void(0);\" class=\"sw_pref\" id=\"id_sc\" title=\"Inst\xC3\xA4llningar"]
- ["/?FORM=Z9FD1\" class=\"b_logoArea"]
- ["javascript:\" class=\"ftrH\" id=\"h5055"]
- ["javascript:\" class=\"ftrH\" id=\"h5056"]
- ["http://avalanche.pc.gc.ca/bulletin-eng.aspx?r=5&amp;d=TODAY"]
- ["http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=SERP&amp;br=ro&amp;mkt=sv-SE&amp;dl=sv&amp;lp=EN_SV&amp;a=http%3a%2f%2favalanche.pc.gc.ca%2fbulletin-eng.aspx%3fr%3d5%26d%3dTODAY"]
- ["http://avalanche.pc.gc.ca/index-eng.aspx"]
- ["http://avalanche.pc.gc.ca/"]
- ["http://www.microsofttranslator.com/bv.aspx?ref=SERP&amp;br=ro&amp;mkt=sv-SE&amp;dl=sv&amp;lp=EN_SV&amp;a=http%3a%2f%2favalanche.pc.gc.ca%2f"]
- ["http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248686&amp;CLCID=41D"]
- ["http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9844343"]
- ["http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617297\" id=\"sb_help\" target=\"_blank"]
- ["http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=246338&amp;CLCID=41D"]
- ["#\" id=\"sb_feedback"]
- ["http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/sv-se/bing/dn768284.aspx"]
- ["/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;go=Submit&amp;qs=n&amp;pq=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;sc=0-0&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2&amp;lf=1&amp;qpvt=ip%3a198.103.247.102\" class=\"b_toggle"]
- ["/account/web?sh=5&amp;ru=%2fsearch%3fq%3dip%253A198.103.247.102%26go%3dSubmit%26qs%3dn%26form%3dQBRE%26pq%3dip%253A198.103.247.102%26sc%3d0-0%26sp%3d-1%26sk%3d%26cvid%3d9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2&amp;qpvt=ip%3a198.103.247.102\" class=\"b_toggle"]
- ["/search?q=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;go=Submit&amp;qs=n&amp;pq=ip%3a198.103.247.102&amp;sc=0-0&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2&amp;rf=1&amp;qpvt=ip%3a198.103.247.102\" class=\"b_toggle"]
- ["javascript:void(0);\" class=\"close\" tabindex=\"0\" title=\"St\xC3\xA4ng"]
- ["http://www.microsoft.com/privacystatement/?form=BNPCEU&amp;publ=BNPRRC&amp;crea=58108\" class=\"button"]
```

Any idea what am I doing wrog?

EDIT! Below is a working script I wrote after all the comments/answers to the question. Thanks guys!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'net/http'

if not ARGV.length == 1
        usage
        exit(1)
end

ipaddr = ARGV[0]
@domains = []

def parse_body(domains)
  puts "[*] #{domains.length} potential domain(s) identified to match IP. Parsing results."
  domains.each {|domain|
    @domains << domain[0].gsub("<strong>","").gsub("</strong>","").gsub("https://", "").split("/")[0]
  }
end

begin
  puts "[*] Finding virtualhosts for: #{ipaddr}"
  cookies = ''
  url = URI("http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip:#{ipaddr}")
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
  res.get_fields('set-cookie').each {|cookie| cookies << cookie.split('; ')[0] + '; '}

  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  headers = {
    'Cookie' => cookies
  }
  resp = http.get(url.request_uri, headers)
  parse_body(resp.body.scan(/<cite>(.*?)<\/cite>/))
rescue => err
  #puts "I don't want to print this #{err.message}. Hence commented"
end

if @domains.uniq.length != 0
  puts "[*] Printing out domains that were found associated with IP address."
  puts
  @domains.uniq.each do |domain|
    puts "[*] #{domain}"
  end
else
  puts "[*] Oops!"
end
```

Comment: what output you are expecting and what input you are providing?

Comment: My input as you can see is the "http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A198.103.247.102&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=ip%3A198.103.247.102&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2" data, I expect to match only the hostnames as my regex tries.

Comment: What are you trying to extract exactly ?

Comment: In this singular case `avalanche.pc.gc.ca` that is the domain of `198.103.247.102`, but this is just an example.

Comment: Your question should be written as:  I have this script < copy script >, I have this input < show input> and I expect this output < show desired output> .  It's too hard to figure out what you'e asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `=~` on `Array` instance here:

```
hostname =~ /^(....)/
```

I have no clue what happens, but changing this line to

```
hostname.first =~ /^(....)/
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Probably i missed your idea, but what about using nokogiri?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'

ip = '198.103.247.102'

# Get the domains
uri = URI.parse("http://www.bing.com/search?q=ip%3A#{ip}&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=ip%3A#{ip}&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9a011b0f18e648008dfdabc9f8648fc2")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
begin
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  domaindata = http.request(request)
  domaindata.code
  domaindata.body
  domaindata["cache-control"]
  noko = Nokogiri::HTML domaindata.body
rescue => err
  #puts "I don't want to print this #{err.message}. Hence commented"
end

anchors = noko.css('a').select{|href| href.to_s =~ /http[s]?/}
other_domains = anchors.map{|a| a.attr('href')}.select{|a| a.to_s =~ /http/}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hostname =~ /^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/
```

You're trying to match a full line with only alphanum chars, dot and -

a correct regex with access to first array element (thanks @mudasobwa to point it) would be [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/wY5uW4/1):

```
hostname.first =~ \/\/((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))\/
```

Which match text the same as above, within `//text/` and not within start and end of line.

a better way to access it and store it for next use would be:

```
domain = hostname.first[\/\/((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]))\/,1]
```

All in all if you want to get the domain I would do a simpler regex like this:

```
domain = hostname.first[/\/\/([^\/]+)\/,1]
```

Here you wish any non `/` character (the `[^\/]` part) after `//` and until a `/` is encoutered.

Comment: I bet you did not check this against OP’s code, because it simply won’t work.

Comment: @mudasobwa indeed, I did focus on the regex problem and miss the array one. But that's far from the only problem of OP's code IMHO

Comment: Yes, there are many problems, but this particular question is about what returns `scan`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Yes, but as the OP's hit this problem by wishing to match something, better fix the regex too, am I wrong on this point ?

Comment: Well, it depends. To solve the issue for OP is not always the most helpful approach. Give man a fish, and you'll feed him for a day, I guess you know the ending :)

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, That's why I tried to be more explicit on the regex involved (as I started on this point), the question being a step in the OP quest, I didn't try to go further... I'll see tomorow what I do with this answer